# Persist dom state on route change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have two components each on separate routes. I would like to know how I can keep the DOM elements in the same state on route change. For example I would like for all the DOM elements to have the same css classes applied as before the route change when navigating back to the same component.

I have tried redux persist and using nested routes with switch but none of these seem to work. From the research I have done it appears that React always mounts and unmount the component on route change and I haven't' been able to find a way to prevent this happening.

I would like for the red background color to remain when going back to test1.

```
class test1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addClassFucn = event => {
        $(event.target).parent().css("background-color", "red")
    }

    renderButton() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.addClassFucn}>Click me</button>
                    <Link to="/test2" className="ui button primary back" >
                        test2
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>This is test 1{this.renderButton()}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default test1;


class test2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderButton() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/test1" className="ui button primary back" >
                    back
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>This is test 2{this.renderButton()}</div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default test2;
```

Comment: Add some code and if possible then some images. It will help the community to understand what you want clearly.

Add what you have tried (in a minimum portion).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the logic of how you maintain the state of your component.

Redux persist should work. Just persist all the state that affects how the DOM currently displayed. Afterwards, inside the component, you should do a check whether there is a persisted state or not. If it is then you shouldn't do any change and just render.

Comment: Thanks I do have components level state which does get changed using setState and classes are added to the dom via user interaction with jquery. The only think I know for sure is that the component unmounts and re mounts on rout change but the data from redux store is persisting. Could it be that the component level state which is in the constructor function is causing the re render? I did try and take it out but it made no difference. I have tried numerous things from the web but nothing seems to work. I have the routes defined in app.js and am using link tags to navigate.

Comment: React component will always unmount when it's removed from the DOM (not displayed anymore in the web). I'm sorry but what is the problem here ?

Comment: The problem is I want to show the previous visited state of the page to the user and not the re rendered one.

Comment: Yes, just like i said. Store your component level state in redux, create a new reducer specifically for that. And add a check logic in your component to see if there is already persisted values.

Comment: ok I think the problem is that I am adding css via jquery and that is not persisting. I have to use jquery as there are multiple html elements so need to traverse dom with jquery methods ie parent, child etc.

Comment: Oh yeah. Use state manipulation instead for adding/removing CSS by jquery. Create state boolean, then add this line to the component className={state ? 'style1' : ''}

Comment: The only problem I have is I have map statement producing 4 divs but I only want to add class to the current element and remove from the other 3 divs. With the state it's adding to all 4 divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react's **shouldComponentUpdate()** which by default returns true allowing the component to re render. If useful than you can add the logic to return false which won't all the component to re-render. This is not recognized as best practice though you can refer this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) for more details.

Comment: I did try this but it prevented the page loading at all. Just showed a blank page.